# PHP: whitespaces that do matter

Tags: php, syntax, whitespace

Whitespaces are generally ignored in PHP syntax, but there are several places where you cannot put them without affecting the sense (and the result).

One example is:

```
$a = 5.5;    // five and a half (float)
$b = 5 . 5;  // "55" (string)
```

Do you know of any other examples?

The question is **not about why is that working this way**, but what are situations, when omitting or placing whitespace changes the program, but both versions are syntactically correct.

Comment: Yeah yeah along with all the other quirks in PHP and every other language written and spoken. Sorry what was the question?

Comment: A nice variation of your second case is `$b = 5...5;` - though it constitutes more of a case where spaces would aid readability.

Comment: Does there exist a language where inserting spaces into the middle of tokens *doesn't* change behavior or break something?

Comment: @Dan Grossman: C? `int main(){ printf("Th" "is wi" "ll work!" ); }`

Comment: In C, if you stick a space between a && operator, or between a ++ operator, it changes the behavior, right?

Comment: In MS Excel formulae, the space character can actually **be** an operator depending on its context within the formula (The "Intersect" operator) e.g =A1:C3 B2:D4 would return the range values for B2:C3, the intersection of the two ranges A1:C3 and B2:D4

Answer (score 10):

That one had me going berserk. I present the whitespace of doom:

```
function foo() {
   print "I'm foo.";
}

if (something()) {
    foo();
}
```

When executing, the error was:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function  foo() on line 6

After an hour or so, I found out, the error message *actually* said:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function  foo() on line 6
```

Notice the double spaces:

```
function  foo()
```

It turned out that by copy/pasting the above code (formatted with [`highlight_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php)), a non-breaking space `&nbsp;`, or `0xA0` is *acceptable* in identifiers, so the function call was to `0xA0foo()` instead of `foo()`.

Comment: This happens all the time to me (so I know where to look), because AltGr+Space inserts an nbsp in my keyboard layout, so often I am not quick enough to release AltGr before pressing space, and here we go.

Comment: Wow... Is there a bug filled for this? This surely does not follow what docs say: `A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*.`

Comment: @Mchl I though about filing a bug report for that. [Given how my previous bug reports where handled](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51112) I decided not to. Interestingly enough, `0xA0` (the non-breaking space) fits the regular expression...

Comment: Regarding the bug you're posted a link to: one of the greates flaws of PHP is that it lacks formal specification. This is the reason why bugs like this are filed under 'undefined behaviour, nothing to worry about'. Yes, now I see that `0xA0` indeed fits the regex. I'll nag guys from php doc team about it.

Comment: Bug? No - PHP (except for some dev builds) has always used ASCII, 0xA0 is an 8 bit char - and therefore not defined by this charset.

Comment: @symcbean Why, then, is it documented otherwise, as @Mchl correctly quotes from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)? Do you have source on your statement?

Comment: @Mchl Any progress on the nagging, yet?

Answer (score 3):

You can't put spaces in the middle of a number! Gosh!

```
$x = 10 3.5; //syntax error
```

If you put a space in the middle of an operator, it's no longer that operator!!

```
if (true & & true) echo 'true'; //syntax error
```

If I put a space in the middle of my string, it's not the same string!

```
echo "Hel lo World"; //does NOT print "Hello World"!
```

Sorry, but this question is ridiculous, since of course you can't throw spaces in the middle of tokens without either changing behavior or breaking code. Just the same as in virtually every other programming and written language.

`5.5` is a number, `5 . 5` is a string because `.` is the string concatenation operator. That's just the language's syntax.

Comment: Of course I do understand what is going on there. The question was what are the situations where omitting or placing whitespace affects the program (but both possibilities are correct).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are breaking a single lexical token in two (a bit like breaking `function` into `func tion`, whitespace is indeed not ignored in that way). This is not really interesting, you could come up with many examples when things break that way, the only interesting task is to try to find an example which *works* (i.e. not a syntax error), but differently, e.g.:

```
$a = $x++ + $y;   // x is incremented
$b = $x+ + + $y;  // x is not incremented
```